# Eclipse Beginner Issue - SSH shell via file explorer isn't working as expected

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

For some reason the command line is triggering an extra 3 times and my commands are on a new-line, but the link below which has the same issue doesn't really clearly explain the solution. Thanks

[image]

https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/1076411/

Comment: it seems like everytime i press enter once on my keyboard the shell is treating is as hitting the enter key twice

Comment: Does you `.bashrc` file does customize your prompt ? (Search for `PS1=`). Is yes, it does also appear in Eclipse terminal as far as I saw. You say "SSH shell", what exactly are the editor / plugin you open (what is the Eclipse Terminal you launch? The default native one?

Comment: the default, my .bashrc file was nevercustomized

Comment: You say press "Enter". Waht if you copy paste a command (including the line feed) so that it is auto run when pasted? Is the invite still displayed twice after command (Goal is to see if keyboard related pb?)

Comment: copy and paste? it doesn't auto-run

Comment: I tried in my default Eclipse terminal. Write "echo test". Run it once with `Enter`. Select / highlight the command with mouse AND select it until first car of newline (the clipboard must contain the LF caracter). Then press mouse middle to paste. Then, the command was successfully auto play, just after mouse middle. No need enter

Comment: Run a fresh Eclipse in a Virtual machine. You will be able to compare and play same actions on both. There should be something on your host that modified this prompt :/

Comment: my eclipse terminal doesnt allow for multiline high lighting

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179848/discussion-between-el-teedee-and-valerio-zhang).

Comment: what is your terminal (installation details), and version of eclipse?